# Empty database tables after Visual Studio Web Deploy

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

EF6, Identity 2, MVC5, C# using Visual Studio 2013.2 Express for Web. SQL Express on local PC.

Am trying to publish using Web Deploy to MS SQL 2012.

In the Web Deploy configurations my databases appear and I have configured the Connection Strings in both Web.config as well as the Web Deploy configuration dialog. Test Connection button returns Succeeded.

My EF database gives me an option to "Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start)" and this works ok.

I also have 2 databases that contain tables with data but are not created using EF. The Web Deploy option for these databases is "Update database" with a link to "Configure database updates". Clicking on Configure pops up a dialog box that has "Auto Schema update" checked, but there is no option for Schema and Data - unlike Package/Publish options which allow Schema Only, Schema and Data, etc.

No matter what I do, I can't get my data populated on the destination. The table will get created if it doesn't exist and the schema is even correct, but they are always empty database tables. I've tried everything I can think of and researched Google, MSDN and ASP.NET for any kind of hint without any success.

Is there something special that needs to be done to get database table content to get deployed using Web Deploy?

There are no errors, it's like it doesn't even attempt to publish the data, only the schema.

Anyone know why data might not be getting deployed to the target?

Answer (score -1):

The Web Deploy function loads an "auto schema update" which only transfers the schema. I disabled that and used the Scripting function in the SQL Studio and generated a script that drops the database, recreates it and then transfers the data using both schema and data which you set in the Advanced settings of the script dialog.